# What is the difference between "ŝanĝi" and "ŝanĝiĝi"?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

What is the difference between "ŝanĝi" and "ŝanĝiĝi" and how would you use these verbs in a sentence?

Answer (score 4):

## ŝanĝi: alter or replace

[*"ŝanĝi"*](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/%C5%9Dan%C4%9Di) is *to change <someone or something>* (i.e. *to alter <someone or something>* or even *to replace <someone or something>*. It's a [transitive verb](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitiva_verbo), which means that it always requires a direct object: the thing or person being replaced or altered.

Examples:

> Ŝi ŝanĝas la oleon. — She changes (replaces) the oil.

> Vi ŝanĝis min. — You've changed (altered) me.

## ŝanĝiĝi: become different

[*"ŝanĝiĝi"*](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/%C5%9Dan%C4%9Di%C4%9Di) is *to change*, i.e. *to undergo a change* or *to change itself or oneself*. It's an [intransitive verb](https://lernu.net/en/gramatiko/verboj_kaj_frazroloj#netransitivaj-verboj), which means that it cannot take a direct object.

Examples:

> La vetero ŝanĝiĝis. — The weather has changed. (became different than before)

> Li ŝanĝiĝos. — He'll change. (He will become different than he is now.)

## The *-iĝ-* affix

Most (maybe even all) transitive verbs in Esperanto can be turned into intransitive ones with [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb) meaning (i.e., the subject is also the object) by appending [the suffix *-iĝ-*](https://lernu.net/en/gramatiko/sufiksoj#igh).

Comment: I think there’s an accusative missing in the first example.

Comment: Indeed it was missing. [fixed](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/revisions/5592/5). Btw., if you're sufficiently sure, just [edit] posts to make such corrections.